# How to remove icons from the ubuntu "app grid"

Tags: 22.04, lutris

The other day I installed league of legends on my 22.04 ubuntu through lutris. This created 2 icons in the app grin one called "League Of Legends" and one called "Riot Client". I have since uninstalled league using lutris again but the icons still remain. Any idea of how I could remove them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two locations where ".desktop" files reside:

```
1) /home/<user>/.local/share/applications
2) /usr/share/applications
```

`<user>` would be your username.

In one of these folders should be files like "League.desktop" and "Riot.desktop".

Search for them and delete them. Note that you need "sudo" for deletion of desktop files in /usr/ folders.

Since the uninstall process did not remove the desktop files, I'd consider this as bug (of the app provider). It is part of the uninstall process to remove those files.

Comment: Okay, this helped thanks! But the solution was a bit different for me so I will comment it here. I found these files you are talking about in: /home/<user>/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/Riot Games. Once I deleted them and restarted the pc they were gone.

Comment: Ok, since I don't ever use wine I wouldn't know and you didn't mention. Glad you've figured it out!